# Java: Realizing periodic interruptions in code execution

Tags: java, sleep

Kindly suggest the best realization for the following pseudo-code:

"After every 10 minutes interrupt your business logic and go to sleep for 5 minutes"

Comment: This should implement `Thread.sleep(5*60*1000);` somewhere in your implementation.

Comment: wait() and sleep() ?

Comment: DimaSan, IMHO, your suggestion will yield only one sleep, of 5 minute duration.  I want to have periodic sleeps of 5 minutes after every 10 minutes of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your logic in subloop inside the infinite loop. And use your working time value in the subloop interrupting condition:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final long WORKING_TIME = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    final long SLEEPING_TIME = 5 * 60 * 1000;

    long startTime;
    while (true) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + WORKING_TIME) {
            System.out.println("working..."); // implement your logic here
        }
        Thread.sleep(SLEEPING_TIME); // sleeping for SLEEPING_TIME
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a simple and elegant solution for what I am trying to do (much simpler than timers, multiple threads etc. that I was toying with)

Comment: You are welcome! Sure it's simple enough, but may fit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
final long executionTimeSlice = 10 * 60 * 1_000_000_000;  // in nanoseconds
final long sleepDuration = 5 * 60 * 1_000;  // in milliseconds

while (true) {
    long endTime = System.nanoTime() + executionTimeSlice;

    while (System.nanoTime() < endTime) {
        /* execute stuff */
    }

    Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
}
```

Do note that this depends on `/* execute stuff */` being able to be broken down into individual iterations, each with an expected duration shorter (hopefully much shorter) than `executionDuration`.

---

## Background

The ideal approach would be to use a daemon thread that would `Thread#suspend` the business logic thread every 10 minutes, then `Thread#resume` it 5 minutes later.  Something like this:

```
final long executionTimeSlice = 10 * 60 * 1_000;  // in milliseconds
final long suspendedDuration = 5 * 60 * 1_000;  // in milliseconds
final Thread businessThread = Thread.currentThread();

Thread timerThread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            businessThread.suspend();
            Thread.sleep(suspendedDuration);

            businessThread.resume();
            Thread.sleep(executionTimeSlice);
        }
});
timerThread.setDaemon(true);
timerThread.start();
```

Unfortunately, both [`Thread#suspend()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend--) and [`Thread#resume()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#resume--) are deprecated.  As [this official statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) by Oracle indicates,

> **What should I use instead of `Thread.suspend` and `Thread.resume`?**
>
> ...the prudent approach is to have the "target thread" poll a variable
>   indicating the desired state of the thread (active or suspended).  When the desired state is suspended, the thread waits...